# Set up multiple accounts for one connection in Kannel

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

I am stuck with a problem with Kannel. I have one SMSC (with one IP and port) but I have 2 user accounts for it. The problem is that I can't set up both user accounts for one SMSC in Kannel (only one connection.) Currently I'm setting each user account in a separate connection (2 connections.) I want to run both accounts on one smsc group in case one of them dies. How can I use two accounts with one connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by creating two smsc groups with the same `smsc-id` but with different `smsc-admin-id`, e.g.:

```
group = "smsc"
smsc-id = "my-smsc"
smsc-admin-id = "my-smsc-1"
smsc-username = "login-1"
smsc-password = "pass-1"
... other params...

group = "smsc"
smsc-id = "my-smsc"
smsc-admin-id = "my-smsc-2"
smsc-username = "login-2"
smsc-password = "pass-2"
... other params...
```

When sending to smsbox use the `my-smsc` as SMSC ID. However, if you want to do something like stop-smsc, start-smsc, etc. from the web interface, you have to use the `my-smsc-1` or `my-smsc-2`.

Kannel will treat both connections as the same and will automatically load balance your messages over both connections. If one of them will die, Kannel will automatically move all traffic to the live connection.

Comment: Thanks you for help, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sorry man, I tested and it didn't work as you say. Just only on connection smsc to be implemented(One connection have status "online", the other one have status "connecting/re-connecting"). What is your idea about this thing? Hope your respond!

Comment: I'm guessing then that the second account doesn't work if it's a completely separate smsc group either. This way is no different than using two completely separate smsc groups. I have multiple SMSC connections running like this for years.

Comment: 1. Look for configuration errors, perhaps the non-working connection isn't configured quite correctly. Are you using the same login/password as for the first one? It's quite common that an SMSC would limit accounts to a single connection at the same time.

Comment: 2. If that doesn't help, inquire your SMSC about what limitations they actually have. There are a lot of things that are not specified in the standard, that SMSCs can choose to implement the way they like - for example, the number of simultaneous sessions per account, or connections per IP address, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have turned up both SMSC connections (online status), but I still have a problem: I want load balancing messages (It means the messages are sent in turns to SMSCs). Actually, Kannel send each MT to BOTH smsc in the same time, though I added "smsc-admin-id" parameter. So, can you give me your idea for this error and share with me the kannel.conf file? I will be very appreciate that!

Comment: If you use the same `smsc-id` for two connections, the standard behavior is to load balance, i've never even seen a case when the same message would be sent through multiple connections. Could it be that you're using the same `smsc-admin-id` for both connections? Because that must be different for each connection.

Comment: I tried again and It worked. I grateful for your assistance, it's very useful for me. Thanks again Mr.pilsetnieks!